# ¿Cómo puedo dividir una cadena?

Tags: c

Necesito que después de cada punto, el siguiente carácter sea mayúscula(si esta es minúscula claramente) pero solo si encuentra un punto(no un espacio), para ello pensé en dividir mi cadena y asi evaluar cada parte.

Por ejemplo: *Estoy. Comiendo arroz*, es necesario dividir la cadena? y si lo es, como seria?

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<string.h>

#include<ctype.h>

int main(){

    char cadena[81];

    int i;

    scanf("%[^\n]",cadena);

    
    for(i=0;i<strlen(cadena);i++){

    if(i==0 || cadena[i-1]==' '){
      cadena[i]=toupper(cadena[i]);
    }
   else if(isupper(cadena[i])){

   cadena[i]=tolower(cadena[i]);

        }   
    }
    printf("%s",cadena);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que has intentado?'

Comment: realmente no tengo mucho, con eso cada caracter se convierte a mayuscula si hay un espacio antes, y convierte las mayusculas a minusculas. despues de eso no se que hacer para que despues de un punto aunque haya un espacio no las convierte a mayusculas

Comment: Puedes darnos más ejemplos?

Comment: si, mira, yo introduzco una cadena de caracteres, en ella escribo lo siguiente:       
 "Hola. Como estas". como puedes ver la primera letra debe ser mayúscula, y como sabemos despues de un punto cada letra debe ser mayuscula. pero no se como hacer dicho proceso

Comment: Es en C o en C++? Imagino que lo quieres hacer "a mano" con ciclos y sin muchas funciones de ayuda?

Comment: esto es lo que debe hacer el codigo:                                                                                                        hOLa. eStoY DesComPUEsta.

cuando en realidad deberia ser:

Hola. Estoy descompuesta.

Por supuesto, un lector que domine la gramática podría saber cuáles letras deben ser
mayúsculas y cuáles minúsculas. Para este ejercicio : la primera letra de cada enunciado (que terminaremos con punto) debe ser mayúscula, todas las demás letras deben ser minúsculas.

Comment: @BenjamínGuzmán, mi idea es hacerlo a mano, ya que no se como reutilizar con las funciones para este ejercicio. y es en c++

Comment: Entonces lo que necesitas es verificar que tras un punto haya una mayúscula? o lo que no sabes cómo hacer es modificar la cadena para forzar que la primera letra tras un punto esté en mayúsculas?

Comment: @eferion, "forzar" que después de un punto haya una mayúscula

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que necesitaremos para esta tarea es una variable bool:

```
bool a_mayuscula = true;
```

Esta variable nos permitirá identificar facilmente cuándo hay que forzar una mayúscula.

Ahora se recorre la cadena. Cada vez que encontremos un punto ponemos la variable a `true`:

```
for (char & c : cadena)
{
    if (c == '.')
        a_mayuscula = true;
}
```

Por otro lado, en el mismo bucle, verificamos si el caracter actual es una letra y, de ser así, forzaremos las mayúsculas únicamente si el flag está a `true`

```
for (char & c : cadena)
{
    if (c == '.')
        a_mayuscula = true; 
    else if (isalpha(c) && a_mayuscula)
    {
        c = toupper(c);
        a_mayuscula = false;
    }
}
```

Claro que estamos en C++, no en C, así que lo recomendable sería también usar `std::string` en vez de `char[]`, y `cin` y `cout` en vez de `scanf` y `printf`:

```
std::string cadena;

std::getline(std::cin, cadena);

bool a_mayuscula = true;

for (char & c : cadena)
{
    if (c == '.')
        a_mayuscula = true; 
    else if (isalpha(c) && a_mayuscula)
    {
        c = toupper(c);
        a_mayuscula = false;
    }
}

std::cout << cadena;
```

Answer (score 0):

Retomando un poco de lo dicho por eferion, te presento mi solución.

```
int main() {
    std::string str;

    // hOLa. eStoY DesComPUEsta
    // Hola. estA. ES. una.     prUeba.  ñoño. es. gracioso. ¿pero? pero. Es algo. nueVo. No se que Poner. Se debe llevar acento. éxito
    // Hola. Mundo. Mundial. Texto Texto. Lorem Ipsum. (Bla bla bla).
    // todo. en. minsuculas. (minusculas). ahora si lo escribi. bibibi. bien. mas o menos.
    std::getline(std::cin, str);

    bool should_be_upper = true; // setear a true al inicio porque la primer letra debe ser mayuscula
    bool is_upper;

    for (char& c : str) {
        if (c == '.') // punto encontrado, marcar que la siguiente letra debería de ser mayúscula
            should_be_upper = true;
        // Del manual: isalpha() is equivalent to (isupper(c) || islower(c))
        else if ((is_upper = std::isupper(c)) || std::islower(c)) { // procesar solo las letras
            if (should_be_upper) {
                c = is_upper ? c : std::toupper(c);
                // setear este flag a falso puesto que ya se convirtió a mayuscula y el resto de letras
                // deberian ser minusculas
                should_be_upper = false;
            } else if (is_upper) // convertir a minusculas todas las letras mayusculas despues de la que se convirtio a mayus
                c = std::tolower(c);
        }
    }

    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Básicamente le cambié nada más unos condicionales muy importantes para tener el comportamiento correcto.

Te dejo este pequeño "esquema" para que veas porqué es importante `should_be_upper` y para qué se usa

```
Hola. estA. ES. una.     prUeba. <- caracter
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
TFFFFTTFFFFTTFFTTFFFTTTTTTFFFFFF <- valor de should_be_upper
```

Básicamente es:

1. Iterar hasta encontrar un punto. En cuanto se encuentre, marcar una variable (`should_be_upper`) para denotar que la siguiente letra después del punto debe ser mayúscula.
2. Iterar hasta encontrar una letra. Si es minúscula, convertirla a mayúscula. "Limpiar" la variable seteada en el punto 1.
3. Seguir iterando caracter por caracter, si es mayúscula convertir a minúscula, si se encuentra un punto, entonces estás en el paso 1. Iterar hasta el término de la cadena de texto.

Por lo anterior, el algoritmo tiene comportamiento lineal.

Los resultados son los siguientes (arriba el input, abajo el output)

```
hOLa. eStoY DesComPUEsta
Hola. Estoy descompuesta
```

```
Hola. estA. ES. una.     prUeba.  ñoño. es. gracioso. ¿pero? pero. Es algo. nueVo. No se que Poner. Se debe llevar acento. éxito
Hola. Esta. Es. Una.     Prueba.  ñOño. Es. Gracioso. ¿Pero? pero. Es algo. Nuevo. No se que poner. Se debe llevar acento. éXito
```

```
Hola. Mundo. Mundial. Texto Texto. Lorem Ipsum. (Bla bla bla).
Hola. Mundo. Mundial. Texto texto. Lorem ipsum. (Bla bla bla).
```

```
   todo. en. minsuculas. (minusculas). ahora si lo escribi. bibibi. bien. mas o menos.
   Todo. En. Minsuculas. (Minusculas). Ahora si lo escribi. Bibibi. Bien. Mas o menos.
```

Como puedes ver funciona bien en la mayoría de los casos pero los caracteres como la **é** y la **ñ** no se cambian. Eso es porque `char` tiene 8 bits y por lo tanto solo maneja caracteres ASCII. Si se desea que sí funcione para estos caracteres "especiales", habría que cambiar el tipo de dato a `wchar`. Supongo que no es necesario, pero bueno, es algo que hay que aclarar de esta solución.

Answer (score 0):

> Para ello pensé en dividir mi cadena y asi evaluar cada parte.

No es necesario, puedes recorrer la cadena y usar una bandera para localizar puntos (`.`) la bandera se sube (se pone a `1`) al encontrar un punto y se baja (se pone a `0`) cuando encuentra una letra y la pone en mayúsculas.

Para saber si un carácter es una letra, puedes usar la función [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) de `<ctype.h>`.

```
void procesa(char *frase)
{
    int punto = 0;
    for (char *c = frase; *c; ++c)
    {
        if (isalpha(*c) && punto)
        {
            *c = toupper(*c);
            punto = 0;
        }
        else if (*c == '.')
            punto = 1;
    }
}
```

---

<strike>Para saber si un carácter es una letra, puedes usar la función [`std::isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) de [`<cctype>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cctype).</strike>

```
void procesa(std::string &frase)
{
    bool punto = false;
    for (auto &c : frase)
    {
        if (std::isalpha(c) && punto)
        {
            c = std::toupper(c);
            punto = false;
        }
        else if (c == '.')
            punto = true;
    }
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZFNTsMwEIXX8SlGRcrPgoh103aHxAJuwGY6mSSWEtt1bESFchjOwsHCJC2iYsPCnvGbz89jm5y7px5NO8932lAfa4adtmPwjMNB/WqiaNPeKkTh7Pig1JvVNThviUfMx1BvtxcY0sbjyIX6UMnR2h5cNMHCHhrsR65U0lgPOUbRUoItXOlE8EQ3cLHSI/auw5wKSNOLgyArk5B4rVCw0Tn2AlWL/vecZJLBksNiK7v2kJVZcYsGHxdyUpNS2gQYUJt87fz2QoHfV3rzaCAa6GOLHuQtnhFe0FCHZVkua4pnC8YOR88S4BQ1ewtI1tfoBy4XsUNiGCJ1FoLmwUk9@K/PsRScF/cnXWPfWiA8SpRpU127IRsD7HbXdiTJXk0mxZ8/WPXiP9pziN7AQ6Wmef4G)</kbd>.

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

Has etiquetado tu pregunta como [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), pero todo tu código es [c](/questions/tagged/c), deberás aplicar los siguientes cambios:

- Las cabeceras `<stdio.h>`, `<string.h>` y `<ctype.h>` son de C, en C++ debes usar la versión adaptada, que es el mismo nombre con prefijo `c` y sin extensión: `<cstdio>`, `<cstring>` y `<cctype>`.
- En C++ las cadenas de caracteres se gestionan con el objeto `std::string` que se define en la cabecera `<string>`, no debes usar `<string.h>`.
- En C++ la comunicación con la consola se hace con objetos de flujo de datos `std::cin` para leer (`c`onsole `in`put) y `std::cout` para escribir (`c`onsole `out`put), estos objetos residen en la cabecera `<iostream>`, no uses `<stdio.h>`.

Teniendo en cuenta los puntos anteriores, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

void procesa(std::string &frase)
{
    bool punto = false;
    for (auto &c : frase)
    {
        if (std::isalpha(c) && punto)
        {
            c = std::toupper(c);
            punto = false;
        }
        else if (c == '.')
            punto = true;
    }
}

int main(){

    std::string cadena;
    std::getline(std::cin, cadena);

    procesa(cadena)
    std::cout << cadena;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: lo siento, lo confundi con c++, cuando en realidad es c